# Microsoft Office 2007 Terminal Servers Licensing Requirements

Tags: terminal-server, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

If I have a Terminal Server that is accessed by 50 users, how many keys do I need for all users to have access to Microsoft Office?

I know that only office editions with VLK will work on Terminal Services, but I don't have any experience with VLK's and the information I find on the Internet isn't giving me any kind of concrete answer.

Currently I think the answer is that I need 50 VLK's, and I really hope that isn't the case as the price is quite high.

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them this question? You did ask them first, didn't you? No? What about one of their resellers or licensing experts?

Comment: I have had the "pleasure" of dealing with Microsoft in the past regarding licesning, I haven't asked them. I am still waiting to hear back from a reseller.

Comment: Yet another question on the [taboo subject of licensing](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/625/should-licensing-questions-be-closed). You are correct BTW, you need 50 licenses for 50 users.

Answer (score 1):

Each client needs its own license.  If you already have an open/volume license for their desktop/notebook, you don't need additional licenses for the terminal server.

Comment: The clients only have OEM licenses.

Answer (score 0):

We support a client with 20 or so TS CALS on their TS and they were looking to install Office for remote workers. The simple answer I was given from Microsoft's licensing people was to buy 20 Office CALs, one for each user that could log into the server. I asked if it would be acceptable to limit the number of users on the TS box to 10 and only buy 10 licenses and was told that would be acceptable to them. (At the time, we weren't making heavy use of the server yet, but would be in future.)

This was during a licensing audit that was remarkable laissez faire; the whole process took a year with my contact going on vacation for a solid month at one point. They certainly weren't draconian about it, even though the client's Office licensing on workstations was a total disaster.

Since then the client has slowly purchased addition Office CALS every few months when the IT budget allows.